# It is possible to include referenced assembly to exe file with roslyn?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, roslyn, static-linking

I'm creating application which generate some C# code and then compile this code into exe file (using CSharpCompilation.Create function). And I have some dll (.NET assembly) with required runtime functions. I want to merge this dll into generated exe file. It is possible?

Comment: Linking code directly into an executable is called "static linking".  I have no idea if .net can do that for an existing DLL that's normally loaded at runtime. (dynamic linking).  But that's what it's called in general, so maybe searching on that will help.

Comment: Have a look at fody costura